# Can't Scrape a table from naturereport.miljoeportal.dk using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from the following site (https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1)

I am using rvest and the Selector Gadget to try to make it work, but so far I have only been able to get it in text form.

## What I need to extract:

I am mostly interested in extracting the number of species of two areas the **Stjernearter**, and the **2-stjernearter**, as seen in the image below:

[image]

As seen in the developer tools of Firefox that corresponds to a table:

[image]

But as I have tried to get the table with Gadget selector, I have not had any success.

### What I have tried:

This are some ideas I have tried with limited success:

I have been able to get the text, but not the table with this 2 codes

```
library(rvest)

rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(":nth-child(9) .table-col") %>% 
  html_text()
```

this gets me the following:

```
 [1] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tStjernearter (arter med artsscorer = 4 eller 5):\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
 [2] "Strandarve | Honckenya peploides"                                                  
 [3] "Bidende stenurt | Sedum acre"                                                      
 [4] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2-stjernearter (artsscore = 6 eller 7):\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"         
 [5] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
 [6] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    N-følsomme arter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    "                       
 [7] "Bidende stenurt | Sedum acre"                                                      
 [8] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tProblemarter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                   
 [9] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
[10] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tInvasive arter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                 
[11] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
[12] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHabitatdirektivets bilagsarter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                 
[13] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
[14] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRødlistede arter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                               
[15] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
[16] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFredede arter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                  
[17] "Ingen arter registreret"                                                           
[18] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAntal arter:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                    
[19] "Mosser: 1 fund"                                                                    
[20] "Planter: 7 fund"
```

And I get a similar result with

```
rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(":nth-child(9) .table-col") %>% 
  html_text2()
```

I have also tried the following codes:

```
rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(":nth-child(9) .table-col") %>% 
  html_table()
```

and

```
rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(".report-body") %>%
  html_table()
```

This will be done for several sites that I will loop from, so I will need it in a table format.

#### Edit

It seems that this code is bringing me closer to the answer:

```
rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(".report-section-body")
```

The eighth element has the table, but I have not been able to extract it:

```
Test <- rvest::read_html("https://naturereport.miljoeportal.dk/HtmlViewer?id=827472&bA=1&bI=1&bN=1%22") %>% 
  html_elements(".report-section-body")

Test[8]
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div class="report-section-body"><div class="table">\n<div class="
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the 'table' isn't actually a table, it's a `div` with a class name of `table-row` or whatever, rather than an actual '<tr>` element. I would extract the text as you have done then probably use some regex to extract the information you need.

Comment: Could you include an example of the table you want as an output?

Comment: To echo @Phil, this is a poorly organized html code, with each line of the table a separate div tag.  Your approach above is correct, it just is going to take more work to clean up responses and organize them, but there is no simple way on this page.

Comment: Can you provide the other sites so that it would provide better insight into your problem? As Phil and Dave2e pointed out you have to use regex to clean and extract the required info.

Comment: I am making a example table, so that you can see what I need, thanks everyone for your comments, so far very helpful

Comment: Example table and also, when you say other sites, do you mean other similar pages within same domain? Do you mean different websites? etc... Can we have examples of the expected use cases (within reason) ?